# Boundary Conditions for Black Holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, boundary-conditions

Consider a metric with one degree of freedom lets say:

$$ds^{2} = -a(r)dt^{2} + a^{-1}(r)dr^{2} + r^{2}d\theta^{2} + r^{2}sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}$$

Einstein's equations are second order differential equations. So in general one needs two boundary conditions in order to solve the equations. I know that at the horizon we want $a(r_{h})=0$ in order to have a black hole (we don't know the position of the horizon though, neither can we fix this). I also know that for $r\rightarrow\infty \rightarrow a(r)=1$, (or some other number in modified theories of gravitation) when there exists no cosmological constant. Is there any boundary condition for the derivative of the metric function $a'(r)$??

Comment: How about using the boundary condition $a(r=\infty)=1$ instead?

Comment: Considering $\Lambda =0$ yes i know that. But i am asking for a boundary condition for the first derivative of the metric function!

Comment: I agree with @Qmechanic we define black hole solutions to be asymptotically flat so $a(r=\infty)=1$ is the natural boundary condition but I'd be interested in, whether there is a physical reason why we should expect anything for finite $r$ for $a'(r)$.

Comment: the assymptotical flatness is natural condition and it is condition for both $a$ and $a'$. You want $a(r=\infty)=1$ and $a(r=\infty)=O(1/r)$, if i remember correctly from lecture. However, i don't remember why the second condition is needed.

Answer (score 2):

With your one degree of freedom Ansatz, the Einstein Equation reduces to a first order instead of a second order equation.

In particular

$$R_{\theta\theta}= 1-a(r)-r a'(r) $$.

The equation $R_{\theta\theta}=0$ has as its most general solution

$$ a(r) = 1- \frac{X}{r},$$

with $X$ a free parameter. This solution also solves the remain Einstein Equations.

This solution automatically satisfies the condition $a(r=\infty)=1$. The remain freedom in the parameter $X$ is fixed by requiring that the mass of the solution is $m$. Since your Ansatz is spherically symmetric it is most convenient to calculate the Komar mass

$$ \frac{Gm}{c^2} = \frac{1}{4\pi} r^2 \int_{S^2}d\Omega n_\mu \sigma_\nu \nabla^\mu K^\nu =\frac{1}{2} r^2 a'(r) = \frac{X}{2}.$$

If you wish, you could have interpreted the last condition as a boundary condition at infinity.

Comment: I am familiar with what you mention. I expected an answer about the Komar integral. My native language is not english and i cannot express correctly what i have in mind. I wonder if there is a  physical reason for a boundary condition foer $a'(r)$. And what happens in modified theories of gravity when one comes across higher order equations?? I am asking in the GR frame since from there you go to modifeid theories of gravity.   Do you think i should rephrase? Your answer is 100% correct and i will accept it if there will be no other answers.

Comment: @ApolloRa: the fact that the spacetime contains total energy momentum $P^{a}$ is the physical reason.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Could you please explain it further?

Comment: I would say that the most intuitive explanation of the boundary condition is that far away from the black hole you are attracted to the center the same way you would be attracted to a weak-gravity source of total mass $M$.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't the other boundary layer be defined by the Schwarzschild radius?

$r_s = \dfrac{2GM}{c^2}$